# Online Store is authorised but did not take the funds yet (initially deduced and then returned to my bank account)

Tags: debit-card, online-payment, transaction

Recently, I've done an online shopping for (~240 GBP) using my debit card (british bank). I have seen that the money has been initially deduced from my bank account, which I assumed was all fine, because they probably locked my money while preparing my order.

Once they dispatched and delivered the items to me, the money appeared on my bank account, but suprisingly it is not locked, e.g. it is not in 'pending' transaction, hence the amount previously paid can be fully accessed and used by me.

This is what you might find on their website:

> 1. If you have paid using a credit or debit card, payment will be authorised when you submit your order, but we won't take the funds from your card until we're about to prepare your order for dispatch.
> 2. If you paid using your Paypal account, the funds will be debited upon
>      you placing your order with us.
> 3. If you paid with Amazon Payments, your card will be billed once we
>      dispatch your order.

Since the money which got transferred back to me is fully accessible for me, I wonder how are they going to take that payment back. Since it is not in 'pending transactions', i.e. not blocked in any way, technically I can have too little amount of money on the account linked to debit card that I used while making the order.

(Usually, I tend to have as little as possible on my debit card account. Those are my rationals - keep it short just in case you'll lose your card or phone. For now I left the equivalent of the payment on that account just in case).

[Online Shop Payments and Delivery FAQ](https://www.sigmasports.com/payment-and-delivery#4)

---

Finally, the amount was deducted from my account again. Likely, there was enough amount available.

Comment: Hi Mr.Nimelo - can you clarify what exactly your question is?

Comment: How is that possible that the money has been deduced from my account, when there was no sign of 'pending' transaction on my account for more than a week + why does this happen that money has bounced back and forth from and to my bank account during that week?